# Why does Tomcat 6 hang when I shut it down?

Tags: tomcat

I have Tomcat 6.0.24 64 bit installed on two Windows Server 2008 boxes as a Window's service. I use the Tomcat Monitor application to start and stop Tomcat. Randomly on both boxes, the server will not shutdown when the Stop Service option is selected. Both Start Service and Stop Service remain grayed out until I open a task manager and kill tomcat6.exe. This also happens with Tomcat 6.0.20 installed on these boxes, however it does not happen on my 32 bit Windows 7 machine. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the recent release, Tomcat 6.0.26, resolved this issue.

Comment: I've been having the same issue (on Mac OS X 10.6) as the OP, but upgrading to 6.0.26 didn't fix anything. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It could very likely be a web application installed in Tomcat that refuses to shut down properly. Can you get a thread dump of the Tomcat when it hangs on shut down?

Comment: I can't choose the Thread Dump option whenever the shutdown process hangs.